# Returning a Django file with posted data written on it - Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to return a PDF file whenever an user passes on some data using POST method and that PDF file should have the POSTed data written on it, I have managed to develop an api that accepts the data passed on by the user and writes the data to a PDF file but I have no idea how to return the PDF file to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following within your view:

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename='+pdf_file_name
# now do stuff to create the pdf as you want it
return response
```